# Detecting a change in model

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django for a web application and I want to implement some code to detect changes in my model (and use that to update the model). I have fiddled with `save`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.somevalue == 0:
            self.someothervalue = timezone.now()
        else:
            self.someothervalue = None

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

but this will also update `someothervalue` to `timezone.now()` when `somevalue` already *was* 0. I want it only to update if it *becomes* 0.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch).

Comment: @solarissmoke I checked that, but I don't seem to have the "old" instance, like I do with an update trigger in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but should work. You cache the previous value inside `__init__` and detect if it has changed inside `save`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.prev_somevalue  = self.somevalue

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.somevalue == 0 and self.prev_somevalue != self.somevalue:
            self.someothervalue = timezone.now()
        else:
            self.someothervalue = None

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

Alternatively, if you are using forms  you could do that on the ModelForm level by using the [changed_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data) property.

Lastly, if you want to use signals, you should use the `pre_save` signal and retreive the previous from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this way of checking for changes in the save method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        db_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=self.id) # this is the copy of the object saved in the database
        if self.somevalue == 0 and db_object.somevalue != 0:
            self.someothervalue = timezone.now()
        else:
            self.someothervalue = None

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```